# apply Clean Architecture principles to recycler view pagging with Adapter Design Patterns and Jetpack Pagging

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-recyclerview, android-jetpack, clean-architecture

I want to build an app following clean architecture principles. There is a recycler view with pagination which asks data in the domain layer and domain gets from the Data layer
as 
     `List<ToiletPaper>`. I want to use Pagging lib from Jetpack, but it returns

```
PagedList<ToiletPaper>
```

Since Data and Domain layers should not be bound to any platform or frameworks I don't want to include them in these layers. How to add Jetpack Paging Library with Adapter Design Pattern without changing the Domain layer?

[my source code](https://github.com/NurseyitTursunkulov/KittyFacts)

Comment: I'm sure you can cast it to `Object` then cast it to `PagedList<T>` and see if your architectural boundaries are helping you or just making your code less safe.

Comment: I think it is not safe to do so.

Comment: Then you have two options: 1.) don't use Paging, 2.) allow data to know about paged list builders 3.) implement Jetpack Paging yourself by hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [PagedList Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/PagedList):

> All data in a PagedList is loaded from its DataSource. Creating a
>   PagedList loads the first chunk of data from the DataSource
>   immediately, and should for this reason be done on a background
>   thread. The constructed PagedList may then be passed to and used on
>   the UI thread.

In Clean Architecture, **we put data sources inside Data layer**. That means if you decided to use Jetpack's Paging Library, you need to import the library as a part of Data and Domain dependencies.

I will provide you step-by-step guide of how to implement it in Clean Architecture in general cases:

**Data Layer**

1. Create either [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) (recommended [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging#data)) or a data source factory (the hard way).
2. Create a method to query/get the data from the datasource, which returns `DataSource.Factory`.

   ```
   @Dao
   interface ToiletDao {
       @Query("SELECT * FROM toilet")
       fun getToiletPapers(): DataSource.Factory<Int, ToiletPaper>
   }
   ```
3. Provide a method inside Repository to access the method you just created.

   ```
   fun getToiletPapers(): DataSource.Factory<Int, ToiletPaper> {
       return toiletDao.getToiletPapers()
   }
   ```

**Domain Layer**

Create a use case or interactor to access the `getToiletPapers()` from Repository, and cast it to `LiveData<PagedList<>>`:

```
class GetToiletPapers @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: ToiletRepository
) : UseCase() {

     fun execute(): DataSource.Factory<Int, ToiletPaper> {
         repository.getToiletPapers()
     }

}
```

**Note:** This class is **just an example** for easier explanation.

**Presentation Layer**

1. In your ViewModel class, call `getToiletPapers.execute().toLiveData(pageSize = 10)` and store the value inside a `LiveData`.
2. Use `PagedListAdapter` to load the data into RecyclerView.

I won't explain the detail of how to use PagedListAdapter, as there are answers of such question available in this community. Hopefully this guide will help you!

Comment: domain layer can not have platform-specific LiveData<PagedList>

Comment: Hi @NurseyitTursunkulov, I have updated my answer. Please check it :)

Comment: Great answer! :) And what about the same with Paging 3 ? )